# how to label 3d model for segmentation task

Tags: deep-learning, image-preprocessing, image-segmentation, image, 3d-object-detection

I'm working on **3d meshes** dataset, i have to label it to train my deep learning model for a segmentation task like the picture shows.

[image]

I spent days looking for a tool to label my 3d data but unfortunately i found nothing..

What tool i can use to label my data (3d mesh, .obj files) for segmentation task?

Comment: I'm working on a tool to do just that; would you mind sending me the teeth example obj file for testing purposes ?

Comment: i can't share the original objects with you because they belong to real person and we have privacy agreement, but i can share with you some edited objects of teeth, or some other obj objects of human body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do manual annotation/labeling for 3D objects using blender and it is difficult to explain only by text, so I recorded a video explaining it with the code a wrote.

You can find that here:
*https://github.com/hamzam0n/3D_objects_annotation*

Answer (score 0):

This segmentation editor might help you https://github.com/Hitachi-Automotive-And-Industry-Lab/semantic-segmentation-editor

or have you already found another good one meanwhile? If yes,can you please share that as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have already found an easy way to do manual segmentation.. i used BLENDER.. if you need more details you can just ask me and i will be happy to give you more details.

Comment: @hamzamon I have the same problem and would be very interested to know how blender solves this problem. Thanks！

Comment: @huaiqiangsun the technique is a bit complicated, it should be explained in a video for better understanding, i will make a video when i'm available and i will upload it here as an anwser with some explications

Comment: @hamzamon could you please capture your process and upload to youtube or just write the steps down? I'm interested too.

Comment: @SergeyFilkin sorry for the late, i just published it